# Can't manage to set up dev enviroment with docker-compose (apache, php, mysql, angular)

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

It's been more than 15 years since I've wrote my last application. Now, getting back meand learning all the new stuff, so please be patient.

My intent here is to create a dev enviroment for my application. I have a pré-built template for the frontend (which uses angular) and I want to create the backend with php+mysql.

I managed to create a fully functional backend with apache+php+mysql, but I'm having trouble setting up the service which will run the frontend.

The problem is: when I run docker-compose up -d, the services start. I can access successfully the localhost:8001 (php index page) and localhost:8080 (adminer mysql page), but I can't access localhost:3000 to see the files on the node service.

All help here is welcome.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  php:
    build:
      #context: .
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <my_pass>
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  nodejs:
    build: 
      context: ./ui
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    #user: node
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - ./ui:/home/node/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Here is my ./ui/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:15.12.0-alpine3.13
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
```

Thanks a lot!!

EDIT 01: The container doesn't show on docker ps after running docker-compose up -d.

EDIT 02: Just found out that on the the Docker Desktop, on the container instance nodejs, it is not up and have this error:

```
> cuba@0.0.0 start
> ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

See "/tmp/ng-Bdlkhp/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

EDIT 03: Saw some tips suggesting to run "npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular" and I added it to the Dockerfile, and then got the error bellow.

```
 => ERROR [6/6] RUN npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular   6.6s
------
 > [6/6] RUN npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular:
#9 6.545 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
#9 6.548 npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
#9 6.549 npm ERR!
#9 6.549 npm ERR! While resolving: cuba@0.0.0
#9 6.549 npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@11.0.9
#9 6.549 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
#9 6.550 npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~11.0.2" from the root project
#9 6.550 npm ERR!
#9 6.550 npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
#9 6.550 npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@">=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0" from codelyzer@5.2.2
#9 6.550 npm ERR! node_modules/codelyzer
#9 6.551 npm ERR!   dev codelyzer@"^5.2.2" from the root project
#9 6.551 npm ERR!
#9 6.551 npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
#9 6.551 npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
#9 6.551 npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
#9 6.552 npm ERR!
#9 6.552 npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
#9 6.559
#9 6.559 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#9 6.559 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-29T22_17_00_378Z-debug.log
------
ERROR: Service 'nodejs' failed to build
```

Comment: What error do you see when you enter `localhost:3000`? Also does your application listen on port `3000`? Maybe it's `80` and you should change port mapping.

Comment: The error I get is ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. But the problem is greater than that... when I rum docker-compose up -d, the container doesn't go up. it doesnt show on docker ps.

I get this error on the console of the https://imgur.com/a/MHVc1ZU

Comment: Regarding `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, you should probably edit your database connection info. Is that `localhost:3306` or `db:3306`? Which one? Regarding your node error, see if module is installed.

Comment: Can you try `COPY . /usr/src/app` first then `RUN npm install -g @angular/cli` Also do not use `-d` to see logs with error.